# Generify String Implementation in Subclasses

Tags: scala

I have the following trait and implementations:

```
sealed trait NodeIdIdentifier {
    def asString: String
  }
  case class NumericTwoByteIdentifier(value: Byte) extends NodeIdIdentifier {
    override def asString: String = value.toString
  }
  case class NumericFourByteIdentifier(value: Short) extends NodeIdIdentifier {
    override def asString: String = value.toString
  }
  case class NumericIdentifier(value: Int) extends NodeIdIdentifier {
    override def asString: String = value.toString
  }
  case class StringIdentifier(value: String) extends NodeIdIdentifier {
    override def asString: String = value.toString
  }
```

As it can be seen that I have to write the `asString` override in all my subclasses. Is there an elegant way of doing this? I don't like the idea to repeat the overrides. I would rather have my trait to define the `asString` behavior and apply it to the subclasses. Any ideas? Would rewriting this in terms of context-bound help me with much more elegant code? I managed to resolve this with using a field of type Any on my trait, but that does not look elegant and it too broad for a type!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `toString` comes from `java.lang.Object` which is the class that every class in Java implicitly extends. Type `Any` from Scala translates to Java's `Object`.

We can take advantage of that and create field `value:Any` in `NodeIdentifier` and use it to provide the implementation of `asString`:

```
sealed trait NodeIdIdentifier {
    def value: Any

    def asString: String = value.toString
}

case class NumericTwoByteIdentifier(value: Byte) extends NodeIdIdentifier {}

case class NumericFourByteIdentifier(value: Short) extends NodeIdIdentifier {}

case class NumericIdentifier(value: Int) extends NodeIdIdentifier {}

case class StringIdentifier(value: String) extends NodeIdIdentifier {}
```

```
StringIdentifier("hello").asString //"hello"
​
NumericIdentifier(100).asString //"100"
```

Of course, we can also make `NodeIdIdentifier` take type parameter:

```
sealed trait NodeIdIdentifier[T] {
    def value: T

    def asString: String = value.toString
}

case class NumericTwoByteIdentifier(value: Byte) extends NodeIdIdentifier[Byte] {}

case class NumericFourByteIdentifier(value: Short) extends NodeIdIdentifier[Short] {}

case class NumericIdentifier(value: Int) extends NodeIdIdentifier[Int] {}

case class StringIdentifier(value: String) extends NodeIdIdentifier[String] {}
```

Comment: In fact I ended up doing more or less the same thing. But that Any type on the value is too broad. I'm thinking of applying some context bounds to restrict it may be!"

Comment: @sparkr You can make `NodeIdIdentifier` generic, but since `toString` is defined in `Object` we can in this very specific case use `Any`.